# Django forms.py constructor behavior

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am facing a very strange issue in Django 1.6.5.

At some point I need to pass a user object in to my forms.py and so I define an `UploadFileForm` like below:

```
# forms.py

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, myuser):
        print myuser
```

In my views I instantiate `UploadFileForm` like this:

```
# views.py

form = UploadFileForm(myuser=request.user)
```

And everything works OK as expected. Now, if I change `forms.py` to this:

```
# forms.py

class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, myuser=None):
        print myuser
```

every time I request the particular page, Django will print `myuser` **4 times**! The first time the user name will print normally but the other 3 it will simply print `None`.

Any clues why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. *I know that the proper thing to do would be to first call `super()` on the parent but it turned out that the behavior remains the same and as such I kept it this way for brevity*

**UPDATE**

This is the full views.py code:

```
@login_required
def uploadTool(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do various irrelevant stuff
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/OKPage/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm(myuser=request.user)

    return render(request, 'uploadForm.html', {'form': UploadFileForm})
```

**UPDATE 2**

I think it's getting a bit creepy. I changed again `forms.py` to this:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i, j in kwargs.iteritems():
            print i, j
        self.myuser = kwargs.pop('myuser')
        print self.myuser

# console output
myuser jsmith
jsmith
```

However Django won't render the template and will instead complain that it can't find `myuser`!

Finally if I change `self.myuser = kwargs.pop('myuser')` to `self.myuser = kwargs.pop('myuser', None)` Django will now print:

```
# console output
myuser jsmith
jsmith
None
None
None
```

and will again fail to render the template.

Comment: Do you create this form and use javascript that trigger submission? How do you create it in your views? Do you have several views that creates a form? Drop a pdb inside the `__init__` and use inspect to see where your form gets called from.

Comment: Please post your view code.

Comment: @limelights I use no javascript at this point. Plus I'm fairly new to Django and I've no clue how to do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Even though Jamie Cockburn didn't give a straight answer he spotted one of my code errors which it turned out that it was responsible afterall for all this strange behaviour .

In my `views.py` I have this:

`return render(request, 'uploadForm.html', {'form': UploadFileForm})`

when it should have been:

`return render(request, 'uploadForm.html', {'form': form})`

after I made this correction everything went back to normal.

Comment: @JamieCockburn Please post a new answer on this topic and I will immediately accept. You were right from the start even though I believe you didn't knew it.